# Issue with bridge between two edge loops

Tags: edges, looping

I'm trying to bridge a circle with an edge loop of a complex model (see next picture.)

[image: First screenshot: selected edge loops]

However, when I select both edge loops and select to bridge both edge loops (via space => mesh: bridge edge loops), I get the following result. I think I'm missing something but can't get to the reason.

[image: My result]

[image: the objective]

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible, looping requires exact amount of edges in both sides, what you could do is merging all those edges until there is exact amount of edges, or bridging edge by edge manually. BTW what kind of mesh do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way to do it...

Comment: I see. I added a third picture of my alternative solution of what I'm trying to do. I would like to build a solid hull from the edge loop on the left. Just dragging the edges also works and I can cut it in the end. But the resulting mesh is very rough and only has a very limited amount of faces. I'm not sure whether there is a solution to get this done in a better manner. It looks a bit weird.

Comment: But your model looks very complicate, with a lot of lines and trying to work with that is very complicated (maybe you noticed that), can you share your reference image please?

Comment: Yes, the model is pretty complex. It results from a photogrammetry of a face. What do you mean by "reference image"?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Background_Images